# Can partner community user see forecast?

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities

I have a partner community. I created users with the partner user license but I don't know if and how to allow them access to the Forecast tab.
Is this at all possible?
Where can I find documentation about the Partner User capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partner portal or community users will not have access to the Forecast tab .However there opportunities still can roll up and show as hierarchy for only collaborative forecasting type .

You can find more info in the below document link

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=forecasts3_prm_setup.htm&language=en_US

Your users need have to have allow forecasting checkbox checked to allow their opportunities to roll up

[image]

> Opportunities that a partner portal user creates can roll up to the forecast of the accountowner;
>
> note that the account owner must be the person’s forecast manager in the forecast hierarchy for the opportunities to roll up into
>   the forecast.
>
> For example, say Gordon Johnson:
>   • Owns a partner account called Acme

• Has an Acme contact named Anne Smith

• Anne is a partner portal user

• Anne reports to Gordon in the forecasts hierarchy

If Anne adds opportunities in her portal, Gordon sees those opportunities in his forecast; because Gordon is Anne’s forecast manager,
Gordon can adjust forecast amounts based on her opportunities and see how she’s tracking against her quota.

> **However, it’s important
>   to note that partner portal users don’t have access to the Collaborative Forecasts tab or any of its functionality.**